# E or natural log problem, solve the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If someone could explain to me the first step or two so I could solve this that would be great. All the e's are confusing me

Solve the equation. (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

$$e^x − 6e^−{^x} − 1 = 0$$

Comment: Why did you ask the _exact_ same question again, and never ask for clarification nor indicate that you didn't understand the many solid answers you got on the previous question?

Comment: Didn't realize it was the same problem, I'm doing homework review for my test and I got stuck on the same problem again I guess lol. I just forgot what to do at the start

Comment: Notice, $$e^{x}-6e^{-x}-1=0$$ $$e^{x}-\frac{6}{e^{x}}-1=0$$ $$e^{2x}-6-{e^{x}}=0$$ $$(e^{x})^2-3{e^{x}}+2e^{x}-6=0$$ $$e^x(e^{x}-3)+2(e^x-3)=0$$ $$(e^{x}-3)(e^x+2)=0$$ $$\implies e^x-3=0 \implies e^x=3\implies \color{blue}{x=\ln 3}$$
$$\implies e^x+2=0 \implies e^x\neq -2 $$ Hence, the solution of the equation is $\color{blue}{x=\ln 3}$

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply the whole equation by $e^x$, you will get a quadratic on $e^x$:
$$
(e^x)^2-6-e^x=0.
$$

Comment: So now I should substitute a variable to = $e^x?$

Comment: Yes. You solve the quadratic and you'll obtain the possible values for $e^x$, and then you solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You can start out by multiplying all terms of the equation by $e^x$:

$$e^x\cdot e^x - e^x\cdot 6e^{-x} - e^x = 0.$$

You can reduce this to

$$(e^x)^2 - e^x - 6 = 0.$$

Substitute $t=e^x$, and get

$$t^2-t-6=0.$$

This is a quadratic equation in $t$, which you can solve with the usual methods. When you have the solutions for $t$, remember to go back and find the solutions for $x$.

Comment: so when I get (y+2) (y-3) then I substitute $e^x$ back in and set both solutions = 0 and take the $ln$ of both sides to solve for x? Update: and there is only one solution since LN (-2) is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$e^x-6e^{-x}-1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(e^{-x})(e^x-3)(e^x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(e^{-x})=0\vee(e^x-3)=0\vee(e^x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{-x}=0\vee e^x-3=0\vee e^x+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{-x}=0\vee e^x=3\vee e^x=-2$$